# Uncaught ValidationError; mongoose and mocha

Tags: node.js, mongodb, error-handling, mongoose, mocha.js

I have an instance method on a mongoose schema, and I cannot catch errors it throws with mocha.

The method does not throw, it calls back with error as param, but mocha test doesn't catch that and I get an uncaught error.

Here's an example module, using mongoose to just do something as a method:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var model;

function init(callback) {
  mongoose.connect('localhost/test', function() {

    var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
      a: String
    });
    schema.methods.act = function(param, cb) {

      if (!param) {
        console.log('Failing, no param.');
        return cb(new Error('Text'));
      }
      this.a = param;
      this.save(cb);
    };
    model = mongoose.model('schema', schema);
    callback();
  });
}

function run(cb) {
  var instance = new model();
  instance.save(function(err) {

    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    instance.act(null, function(err) {

      if (err) {
        console.log('An error:', err);
        cb(err);
      };
    });
  });
}

module.exports = {

  init: init,
  run: run
};
```

Here's a simplified mocha tester:

```
require('should');
var myModule = require('./testm');
describe('test', function() {

  before(function(done) {
    // prep stuff
    myModule.init(done);
  });

  it('should catch the error', function(done) {

    myModule.run(function(err) {

      console.log('Error here:', err);
      err.message.should.equal('Text');
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Running the test doesn't work as expected:

```
mocha test


  test
Failing, no param.
An error: [Error: Text]
Error here: [Error: Text] Text
    1) should catch the error


  0 passing (30ms)
  1 failing

  1) test should catch the error:
     Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'equal' of undefined
      at /home/zlatko/tmp/test.js:14:26
      at /home/zlatko/tmp/testm.js:35:9
      at model.schema.methods.act (/home/zlatko/tmp/testm.js:14:16)
      at Promise.<anonymous> (/home/zlatko/tmp/testm.js:31:14)
      at Promise.<anonymous> (/home/zlatko/tmp/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:177:8)
      at Promise.emit (events.js:98:17)
      at Promise.emit (/home/zlatko/tmp/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:84:38)
      at Promise.fulfill (/home/zlatko/tmp/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:97:20)
      at handleSave (/home/zlatko/tmp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:133:13)
      at /home/zlatko/tmp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:408:16
      at /home/zlatko/tmp/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection/core.js:128:9
      at /home/zlatko/tmp/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1195:7
      at /home/zlatko/tmp/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1903:9
      at Server.Base._callHandler (/home/zlatko/tmp/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:453:41)
      at /home/zlatko/tmp/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:487:18
      at MongoReply.parseBody (/home/zlatko/tmp/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/responses/mongo_reply.js:68:5)
      at null.<anonymous> (/home/zlatko/tmp/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:445:20)
      at emit (events.js:95:17)
      at null.<anonymous> (/home/zlatko/tmp/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:207:13)
      at emit (events.js:98:17)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/zlatko/tmp/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:440:22)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:765:14)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17)
      at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:427:10)
      at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:423:5)
      at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:166:9)
      at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:128:10)
      at TCP.onread (net.js:529:21)
```

What can I be doing wrong?

*Update:* changed to be more clear.

Comment: Well, somehow your `require('should')` is not working properly. Have you tried to set it to a variable, like the docs recommends: `var should = require('should')`? Other thing: the first error that you described in your question before was on what my answer was based. When you remove that part, my answer stops making sense. You should consider putting that part back again, an also keep your updates, so other people can understand the whole context.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, @Louis answer is the best way to check for an error in asynchronous scenarios: just assert if it exists, their types and so on.

But, if you really want to throw an error when you receive it in your callback, you can do it with [`chai-as-promised`](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised/), like:

```
it('should catch the error', function() {

  return Promise.resolve(function () {
    myModule.run(function(err) {

      if (err) {throw err;}
    });
  }).should.eventually.throw(Error);
});
```

In my example, I'm using `should.js` as the assertion library, but you can use whatever assertion library you want.